# ES Classes how to reference methods inside other methods

Tags: javascript

I typically would write something like the below with a function, however, I thought I'd try to ES class syntax.

I am a little stumped, how do I access dot() from the render() method?

I have tried `this.dots()` inside the `render() method`.

Which outputs the following
"Uncaught TypeError: this.dots is not a function"

```
class Carousel {

  constructor(name, dots=false) {
    this.name = element(name)
    this.frames = element(name).childElementCount
    this.dots = dots
  }

  dots() {
    console.log(`From method: ${this.dots}`)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`${this.frames}`)
    dots()
  }

}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
  let usp = new Carousel('uspBar', true)
  usp.render()
  
})
```

For posterity here is the working solution:

```
class Carousel {

  constructor(name, dots=false) {
    this.dot = dots
    this.name = element(name)
    this.frames = element(name).childElementCount
    this.dots = this.dots.bind(this)
  }

  dots() {
    console.log(`From method: ${this.dot}`)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`${this.frames}`)
    this.dots()
  }

}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
  let usp = new Carousel('uspBar', true)
  usp.render()
  
})
```

Comment: @OriDrori thank you, I thought that was the case, however it does not work for me. I get a "app.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: this.dots is not a function" error? any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the constructor you have to bind `dots`:

```
constructor(name, dots=false) {
     this.name = element(name)
     this.frames = element(name).childElementCount
     this.dots = this.dots.bind(this);
}
```

then in the `render` method call it like this:

```
this.dots()
```

Comment: Thank you Alan, that is very much appreciated. What materials can I read? I went through the Mozilla JS Class documentation and could not find a solution. How  did you know to bind(this)? Thank you again.

Comment: I found [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/class) very helpful take a look